# totalUnits is not iterable error on doing sum using forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am iterating over skidList array and doing sum of quantity of all the products in that skid by using `totalUnits`.
 However I am getting `totalUnits not iterable` error.
I tried using let instead of var but it gives the same error.

```
    const createPurchaseOrder = skidList => {
        const [expectedItems, setexpectedItems] = useState([]);
        const [actualItems, setactualItems] = useState([]);  
        skidList.forEach(skid => {
            var totalUnits = 0;
            Object.keys(skid).forEach(key => {
                totalUnits += parseInt(skid[key], 10);
            })
            setexpectedItems(expectedItems.concat([ ...totalUnits ]));
            setactualItems(actualItems.concat([0]));
        })

        newPurchaseOrder.expectedItems = expectedItems;
        newPurchaseOrder.acturalItems = actualItems;

        console.log(newPurchaseOrder);
            
    }
```

Comment: You're using `totalUnits` with the spread operator: `[...totalUnits]`. However, the spread operator is intended to be used with arrays or objects, not strings or numbers. Instead of `setexpectedItems(expectedItems.concat([ ...totalUnits ]))`, do you mean `setexpectedItems(expectedItems.concat(totalUnits))`?

Comment: That's right. I did 
let expectedItems = [];


            skidList.forEach(skid => {
                var totalUnits = 0;
                Object.keys(skid).forEach(key => {
                    totalUnits += parseInt(skid[key], 10);
                })
               expectedItems.push(totalUnits);
               
            })

Comment: It solved the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`totalUnits` is of type `Number`. How you expect it is iterable by using `[ ...totalUnits ]`. `...` must apply to something iterable like `array` rather than a primitive type like `number`